# why do spaces break my code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

why is `el+ = v[i]` different from `el+=v[i]` ?
i thought javascript doesn't care about spacing.
thanks, Any answers are appreciated it. and please don't put my question on hold. i'm here trying to learn.

```
var v = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
var el="";

for(i=0; i<v.length; i++){
    el+ = v[i]; // not working because of spaces, but why?
    // el+=v[i]; // working
}
document.write(el);
```

Comment: I am confused as to why you would think it would work.  What are your trying to do?  el+ is not a valid variable name and has not been defined.  The NOT WORKING looks like you are trying to assign v[i] to el+

Comment: el+=v[i];// will return abcde, but el + = v[i] won't work

Comment: i gave it spaces so it's easy to read. never thought, javascript read it differently.

Comment: Well that would be like trying to give a word spaces to make it easier to read. "A q u i c k f o x" is not easer to read than "A quick fox"    As discussed below `+ =` is not the same as `+=`.  If you want to make it easier to read do it like this: `el += v[i];` that would be allowed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+=` is an operator. It is not a combination of `+` and `=`.

Answer (score 3):

Because `+=` is an [augmented (or compound) assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_assignment) operator, not `+ =`. Similarly, `i++` is fine, but `i+ +` causes a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

```
el+ =
```

it's illegal operator.

```
+=
-=
/=
*=
```

are available for instance

for your case. I will suggest even avoid **for** loop and do instead :

```
var el = v.join('');
```

Comment: = is a valid assignment operator the problem lies more in the fact that el+ is not a valid variable name :-)

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript engine interprets "+ =" differently from "+=". That's just the way it is written.